# Do regular lighters not work at high altitude?

Tags: fire, stoves

Here is what I would consider a regular Bic butane lighter.

[image: bic lighter]

However I have noticed that you can buy **High Altitude** lighters such as this [one.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CX7G0M) Is that **just marketing** or would a **regular lighter not work at high altitudes?**

Comment: What do you consider high altitudes?  The only real problem I've observed has been with piezo igniters, which is why I'd actually expect the "high altitude" one you listed to fare worse than the pictured Bic.

Comment: Smells a bit like a marketing opportunity to me... :)

Comment: I have used that very lighter at 14k+ feet, which is considered "high altitude" by some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it does not matter which lighter you use if it's filled with butane. Lighter would not work if gas temperature close to boiling temperature. For butane it's -1C. For isobutane it's -11C and for propane it's -42C. Also propane has better evaporation properties. That's why gas stoves filled with 20% propane and 80% isobutane.

Comment: but boiling temperature changes with pressure, and pressure changes with altitude...

Comment: @njzk2 under high altitude I understand something like 6000m. So on this altitude with air temperature -35C pressure would be 0.042MPa. Boiling temperature for butane would be -20C. So lighter would not work if my calculation is correct.

Comment: It depends where you carry your lighter. In subzero conditions I used to have an inside pocket kit with a torch (and spare rechargeable batteries) and camera batteries. The lighter could be added to that.

Comment: This is very unclear. What do you mean by "boiling temperature"? What is being boiled? at a low temperature?

Comment: @MartinF the "gas" itself boils.  It's just like water, only instead of boiling at 100 °C at sea level, it boils at -1 °C.  However, you need to get it well above that point to have sufficient pressure for a good flame.  If it helps, imagine a pressure cooker; unless it gets hot enough there won't be enough pressure for the relief valve to blow.

Comment: FWIW, my personal experience is that at temps below freezing, even if kept warm next to the body, regular lighters (i.e. butane) do not work reliably above about 9000 ft or roughly 2500 meters. If you have a refillable lighter you can get an adapter to allow it to work with the isobutane mix used in most canister stoves.

Comment: To clarify the "boiling" remark, lighters are pressurized to the point that the butane is liquid, not gas inside the lighter. In order for the lighter to work, the liquid needs to turn to gas when the valve is open at a sufficient rate to mix with the O2 in the air to burn.